# Why isn't this Facebook Plugin working?

Tags: html, facebook-javascript-sdk

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t9h6W/

```
<body style="margin:0 0 0 0;background-color: #f4f4f4;">
<div>
The JSFiddle has all the code.
</div>
</body
```

Everything seems to be fine, I don't understand why the Facebook Social Plugin isn't working? More-so, how would i reposition the social plug in inside the login form that I have present on the page? No Idea why it isn't working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says,

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
```

Open your browser console and you will see Javascript error.

To reposition the FB login button, you can place the code inside a div and control the div to position the box.

ie., put the fb embed code inside a div like this,

```
<div class="fb-login"> 
    <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</div>
```

Now you can apply style to 'fb-login' class to position the fb button.